# Moving Fancybox navigation into or next to toolbar

Tags: fancybox, fancybox-3

Is there an easy way to move the Fancybox navigation arrows into or next to the toolbar? Ideally, I would like to have them all above my gallery items with the left arrow, then the right arrow, then the close button. I can figure out how to reposition everything using CSS, but I was wondering if there was a quicker/easier way to get the layout I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `buttons` option to specify what buttons and in what order you need:

```
$('[data-fancybox="images"]').fancybox({
  buttons: ['arrowLeft', 'arrowRight', 'close']
})
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jjYOLj?editors=1010